# Redirect mobile users to mobile url

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

Basically I am using a non responsive site where i have a main site

```
www.localhost.com
```

And a mobile site

```
www.localhost.com/mobile/
```

I am using this php code to redirect mobile users

```
$ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
$uachar = "/(nokia|sony|ericsson|mot|samsung|sgh|lg|philips|panasonic|alcatel|lenovo|cldc|midp|mobile)/i";
$smartuachar = "/(ipad)/i";

//if(($ua == '' || preg_match($uachar, $ua))&& !strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'wap'))
if(!(preg_match($smartuachar, $ua)) && ($ua == '' || preg_match($uachar, $ua))&& !strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'wap'))
{
    $Loaction = 'mobile/';

    if (!empty($Loaction))
    {
        ecs_header("Location: $Loaction\n");

        exit;
    }

}
```

The issue i am facing is i want to redirect mobile accessed url to the mobile version url

Lets suppose if this page is requested from a mobile device

```
www.localhost.com/xiaomi-mi-max.html
```

It should redirect it to

```
www.localhost.com/mobile/xiaomi-mi-max.html
```

What options do I have? Also, what is the best practice in this case?
Would appreciate any help.

Comment: "I am using this php code to redirect mobile users" - and what specifically is the problem you are having with this code? (Looks like it only redirects to `mobile/`... have you considered just appending the current `REQUEST_URI` to `$Loaction`?)

Answer (score 1):

Put this code in the .htaccess file of the root directory.

```
  RewriteEngine On

  #condition to check for user agent

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]

  #rewrite rule for example.com => example.com/mobile when useragent is from above

  RewriteRule ^$ /mobile/? [L,R]

  #condition to check for user agent

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} android|avantgo|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge\ |maemo|midp|mmp|opera\ m(ob|in)i|palm(\ os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows\ (ce|phone)|xda|xiino [NC,OR]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a\ wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r\ |s\ )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1\ u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp(\ i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-|\ |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac(\ |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt(\ |\/)|klon|kpt\ |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg(\ g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|e\-|e\/|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(di|rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-|\ |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v\ )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v\ )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-|\ )|webc|whit|wi(g\ |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|xda(\-|2|g)|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-) [NC]

 #rule for example.com/a-b-c.html to example.com/mobile/a-b-c.html when above user agent
  RewriteRule ^([0-9A-Za-z-]+)\.html$ /mobile/$1\.html? [L,R,QSA,NC]
```

**updated**- Now this code works, I have checked on my server.

When everything works as it should, you may replace `R` with `R=301` (permanent redirect).

Comment: This only redirects requests to the document root, not like-for-like URLs as stated in the question.

Comment: @w3dk  I have modified the code and i have checked on my server, it is working. Thanks for pointing out my mistake. Please check it

Comment: Thanks will check it when on work pc and let you know

Answer (score 0):

Use relative URLs instead.

Example:
instead of www.localhost.com/xiaomi-mi-max.html use /xiaomi-mi-max.html - it essentially equals "path to current file"/xiaomi-mi-max.html.

So in case of mobile it will direct to absolute URL localhost/mobile/xiaomi-mi-max.html and in case of desktop to www.localhost.com/xiaomi-mi-max.html as long as it is called from the appropriate path (like www.localhost.com/index.html or www.localhost.com/mobile/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

your question if(!empty($Loaction)) will always return false,  because $Loaction is defined the line before;

how about:

```
if(!(preg_match($smartuachar, $ua)) && ($ua == '' || preg_match($uachar, $ua))&& !strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']),'wap')) {

    header('Location: mobile.html', FILTER_SANITIZE_URL);
    exit();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

$_SERVER and header() will help here.

```
// header("Location: " . $dest) redirects to that path in $dest
// $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] returns "localhost.com" 
// $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] returns "/xiaomi-mi-max.html"
// mobile is simply placed in between, as seen below
header("Location: " . "http://". $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/mobile" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

note: make sure your header function is placed before any HTML is displayed